# Control User Focus during processing VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When a user clicks "go" to run my vba application, it is processing data for about 30 seconds, is there any way to have a box come up during that time that says like "processing" or something, and not allow the user to click anywhere until it is done/goes away?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried displaying a message box, then disabling updating the screen and events until the process is over? The user would be able to close out the message box, but they would be unable to interact with the sheet while you are processing. It would like something like this:

```
MsgBox "Please wait until the process is complete. This may take some time."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Your Code Here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: hmm, I'll give that a try. But how would they know when it is complete, I was kind of hoping for something like a messagebox, but that they couldnt get rid of until the processing was complete.

Comment: Instead of a message box you could try creating a form and disabling the close button. Afterwards, you could manually destroy the frame when your processing is complete. Check out http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=363931 for information on preventing a form from being closed and http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5757 for some information on creating forms

Comment: hmm yea, i feel like there should be an easier way to do want without a form, but yea that should work, thanks for the input. One of these methods will do what I need.